# How to dynamically set the title of a jquery dialog in a repeater?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to figure out how to set the title of a jquery dialog from a dotnetnuke module using a repeater on a .ascx page.

Here is the user control:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblitemName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemName").ToString() %>' />
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
jQuery(function ($)
{
$('#dialogs-Reader .alert').click(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.dnnAlert
     ({
         text: '<blockquote style="font-size:14px;">Just some text.',
         okText: 'Close',
         draggable: false,
         position: ["center", "center"],
         width: ($(window).width()-100),
         height: ($(window).height()-100)
     });
});
$('#lblitemName').change(function ()
{
    var newTitle = $("#lblitemName").val()
    $('#dialogs-Reader .alert').dialog('option', 'title', newTitle).click("open");

    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#lblitemName')
```

Since you're inside a repeater, this will not be the ID of the label anymore when rendered to the page, it will look more like 'dnn_ctr156562_repeaterid_lblitemName', try

```
$('id$=lblitemName')
```

This will add your change event to all labels in the repeater whose ID ends with 'lblitemName'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> $("span.ui-dialog-title").text('My New Title');

For future reference, you can skip google with jQuery. The jQuery API will answer your questions most of the time. In this case, the Dialog API page. For the main library: http://api.jquery.com